# The VB project is targeting ".NETFramework, Version=v4.5"

Tags: .net

[image]

I have no idea what to do, I have a newer version of .NET so I don't know why it is giving me this error!!!!

Comment: Are you afraid your computer will explode if you just click OK?

Comment: ? It still won't load my project if I click ok, I can't edit any code

Comment: Add that to the question, at least it'll be something we could help with then :)

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the project file and the way it's specifying target framework version. If you use source control, roll the project back and see if that fixes it. If you don't use source control, create a new project and copy all source code files across... Then start using source control! NB: When you copy files into the new project, do it using the VS Solution Explorer, not Windows explorer, otherwise the files won't be included in the project and you'll need to Show All Files -> Select new files, Right-click, include in project.

Comment: Creating a new project does not work, I get the same error and am unable to create forms

Comment: Seems like a botched install of VS, .NET or both. Do a clean install of them.

Answer (score 0):

Update your config file:

```
 <?xml version ="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>
 </configuration>
```